# Calculating supplementary angles from intersecting line with direction and line with gradient

Tags: angle

[Example image where I'd be interested in finding angles a and b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wyC2.jpg)A simulated robotic agent is travelling in an known direction heading relative to north as it hits (at for example, 30 degrees) a straight wall (speeed doesn't matter), of which two points on this wall/line are known (i.e. (-3, 7) and (8, 5)). I am wanting to calculate the supplementary angles that are created as the agent makes contact with the wall when moving in its heading direction.

I haven't really done this kind of maths in ages, I'm sure its relatively straight forward, but does anyone know how to perform these sorts of calculation?

Answer (score 0):

The angle $\theta_\text{wall}$ that the wall makes relative to north will be given by
$$
\tan (\theta_\text{wall}) = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}
$$
where $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are the changes in $x$ and $y$ coordinates between two known points on the wall.  (Assuming the $y$-axis points to the north and the $x$-axis points east.)  Once you have this angle, the angle between the robot's path and the line of the wall will just be the difference between these angles:  $\theta_\text{robot} - \theta_\text{wall}$.